# Rest to Return Null Object for Error

Tags: java, rest

In my Rest Service Implementation I have a response as a DTO object I have a requirement where I would like to have the DTO as a null object in case of error or some conditions are not met.

Listed below is the jave code I was wondering if

```
public OutputDTO methodName(InputDTO inputDTO){
try {
   if(Some condition met){
     OutputDTO output =  getResultsFromDatabase()
}
else {
OutputDTO outputDTO =  new OutputDTO();
outputDTO.setStatus("Error");
outputDTO.setStatusMessage("Condition not met");}
}catch(Exception e){
OutputDTO outputDTO =  new OutputDTO();
outputDTO.setStatus("Error");
outputDTO.setStatusMessage(e.toString);}

}
```

Is there a way I can not have the repetitive code that is inside the catch block and the else block, I am asking is there a way I can set the DTO object to be null and do this more efrficently. Also all the DTO inherit from a AbstractDTO which has a status and statusMessage in it

Comment: you can use the `finally` block. The finally block occurs whether or not an error is thrown

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. You can't set an object to null. A variable can be set to null. And you're asking two contradictory questions: avoid the repetitive code, which creates and populates a DTO, and set it to null.

Comment: Initialize **outputDTO** this first outside try statement. and if condition does not met return same object. Rather to init again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `else` part, throw an exception:

```
else {
    throw new Exception("Condition not met")
}
```

Or you can use the `finally` block.

Answer (score 1):

```
public OutputDTO methodName(InputDTO inputDTO){
   OutputDTO outputDTO = new OutputDTO();
   outputDTO.setStatus("Error");
   try {
      if(Some condition met){
      OutputDTO output =  getResultsFromDatabase();
      //if needed you can change the status of outputDTO here 
   }
   else {
      outputDTO.setStatusMessage("Condition not met");
   }
   catch(Exception e){
      outputDTO.setStatusMessage(e.toString);
   }

}
```

Initialize `outputDTO` outside of the conditionals and give it a default status of "Error". If your try block succeeds, then you can change the status of `outputDTO` if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

If the only time you want to get results from a database is on if the condition is met and all other times create a new object then you can use something like this:

```
    try{
        if(...)
            OutputDTO output =  getResultsFromDatabase()
        else
            throw new Exception("test");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        OutputDTO outputDTO =  new OutputDTO();
        outputDTO.setStatus("Error");
        outputDTO.setStatusMessage(e.toString);
    }
```